# Process.Start ignores commands to run apps during compile-time T4 Text Template Transformation

Tags: c#, t4

I am trying to get local svn HEAD revision number executing `svn info` command from code in T4 Text Template. Here's a piece of code that gets result of this command:

```
private string GetSvnInfo()
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName: "cmd", arguments: "/c svn info -r HEAD")
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = Host.ResolvePath(""),
    };
    var process = Process.Start(psi);

    var res = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit(100);

    return res;
}
```

When I run this template it works fine. But when it is executed automatically during build the command is simply ignored.

I also tried to start `svn.exe` instead of `cmd` and pass `info -r HEAD` as arguments there, but then I got Win32Exception on Process.Start(). It seems to be permissions-related problem, but, first, I'm not sure, and, second, I was unable to find anything related to permissions during compile-time T4 Text Template Transformation.

And I also tried different apps, e.g. `sqlcmd` - result is the same.

So the question is - how will I get an app to execute from cmd during compile-time T4 Text Template Transformation? Any help will be appreciated.

I compile my solution in VS 11 under Admin privileges.

Comment: Maybe there is an error that is suppressed. Try throwing something. Can you see the error somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I perform output in comments in a generated file and I was unable to see any error. Unhandled exceptions are compile time errors in this case, by the way

Comment: Did the process start and maybe fail immediately? Launch procmon and look at the timeline of processes (or simply watch all process start events).

Comment: Oh yes, #usr! StandardError showed "unable to execute specified program" (it is my translation from Russian)

Comment: Ok, I've used procmon. I found that when I run it manually devenv.exe process executes "Process Create" operation and I see my cmd there. But when I build solution I see no such operation there

Comment: Oh, when I Build solution this is performed by MSBuild.exe process and procmon reports success on it..

Comment: So both cmd.exe and svn.exe start. What to they return? They must be failing. Redirect their output to a file. Also redirect standard error.

Comment: Redirected ouput is empty and redirected error shows "unable to execute specified program"